# Plastic for casting?

Tags: 3d-models

You mix 10 % clay with 90 % quartz sand, fill a wooden box 1/3, then insert your wax model which includes a funnel, then fill the rest of the box with more clay and quartz sand. After heating to about 90 °C, the wax will melt and flow out of a hole in the bottom. Then you can cast aluminum from the top.

Except I want to do this with 3D printed plastic, not wax. What material would be suited for this?

Comment: Have you seen [this question](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/209/how-can-i-optimize-my-print-for-casting-in-metal)?

Comment: Great answers, thank you. So either get a resin printer and directly print wax (expensive), or print a negative and cast paraffin wax into it after heating to 50C

Comment: You're welcome, does [this previously shared question](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/209/how-can-i-optimize-my-print-for-casting-in-metal) answer your question? If so, we can mark it a duplicate!

Comment: Sure, you can close the question